# Bluetooth activated after resuming from suspend

Tags: systemd, bluetooth

After resuming from suspend, gnome 3 activates "graphically" the bluetooth i.e. bluetooth service is still disabled but the icon of the bluetooth is present if I click on the top right of the screen (even if before I switched that off).

Does anyone has any clue why this happens and how to fix it?

BTW I am using Debian 8.